# update xcode9 - about push new navigationbar bug,whats that?

Tags: ios, push, xcode9, navigationbar

What happened with my navigation bar, when A nav push B vc, vc navigationbar will appear a strange view.

[image]

Comment: might be you are setting self.view background color to cear color or on push you are change navigation transperent or hide.

Comment: thx,but i think its not, cos i have set " self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]"  in [viewDidLoad] and  A push B viewController , i search B viewController code about "transperent" and "navigationBar.hide",but I can't find it,and i remember I haven't used nav transperent or hide

Comment: check you set an image for navigation or clear something image for that

Comment: (A push B )A [viedidload] code : self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
B viewdidiLoad code:
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: try once remove that navigation setting stype tint and all that color

Comment: yes, i did 
A [viedidload] code
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
B viewdidiLoad code: 
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
but its unwork
May be tabbarController problem?